# Do Virtualized systems effect Explain Plans?

Tags: database, postgresql, virtualization, vmware, sql-execution-plan

I'm having strange and different results for explain plans on Postgresql. Postgresql server is installed on a VMWare machine and when executing several explain plans for a given SQL query, different results are returned. It seems to me that the hardware virtualization may provide "erroneous" information to Postgresql server so that it returns "anormal and somewhat random" costs measurements. Am I right or is there any other explanation for those surprising and strange results?

In any case, if you know any, I'd appreciate any helpful docs.

Comment: Is there any way you can capture the output of `explain analyze` over time?

Comment: Sorry,what do you mean? Do you mean having those outputs? I'm actually having this behaviour when executing in VM, but not in "normal" environment.

Comment: He means for you to archive EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query> outputs so we can compare.

Comment: Can you explain why you think OS-level costs are changing?  As opposed to cost estimates based upon the contents & size of a changing database?

Comment: @fche - I agree, this is answer. Data are changing, maybe VACUUM is required.

Comment: @jordani: I don't think it's the answer. Esteve knew enough to examine explain plans, and to compare plans between inside and outside VMWare. I'd be really surprised if he didn't know about VACUUM.

Comment: As far as I know(I'm not a database administrator), VACUUM is needed when new insert and updates are executed (I mean, as databases evolves). In my case, all explain plans are executed sequentially, no one but me is working with the database and there is no batch processes working with the database. Different costs are obtained in sequential executions, with no database changes.

Answer (score 1):

[VACUUM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) should be a regular part of database operations. It's probably not the source of your problem, though.

> We recommend that active production databases be vacuumed frequently
>   (at least nightly), in order to remove dead rows. After adding or
>   deleting a large number of rows, it might be a good idea to issue a
>   VACUUM ANALYZE command for the affected table. This will update the
>   system catalogs with the results of all recent changes, and allow the
>   PostgreSQL query planner to make better choices in planning queries.
>
> The FULL option is not recommended for routine use, but might be
>   useful in special cases. An example is when you have deleted or
>   updated most of the rows in a table and would like the table to
>   physically shrink to occupy less disk space and allow faster table
>   scans. VACUUM FULL will usually shrink the table more than a plain
>   VACUUM would.

Since you got different costs on consecutive executions, one under VMWare and one without, with no database changes, I'd say virtualization is having some effect. I'm pretty sure that a virtual machine would appear to have less RAM than straight hardware, but I don't have a way to test that, or to test its effect on the query optimizer right now.

Comment: all consecutive executions are performed VMWare system. This is the strange behaviour: consecutive executions, without changes in database returns different costs. I know that if changes are done between executions (update, insert, alter... operations) VACUUM may be needed to help planner make better plans, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Plans are not directly affected by the underlying hardware.  They are a product of cost parameters (e.g., `random_page_cost`), memory settings (e.g., `work_mem`), and table statistics.  You ought to be able to verify easily whether the parameter settings are the same between your two instances.  (Ideally one would make adjustments to these parameters based on hardware characteristics, and then you would get different plans on different systems.)  The table statistics are dependent on the actual data in the tables (you did not mention whether you had the same data in both instances) and some random element when the statistics are collected.  Make sure `ANALYZE` has been run.  If you're still clueless, post the plans.